# How to use BeginScope in Azure Application Insights (in https://portal.azure.com)?

Tags: azure, scope, azure-application-insights

My C# code is `log.BeginScope("Testing Scope1");` and `log.BeginScope("Testing Scope2");`. How can I use in Azure Application Insights (in https://portal.azure.com)?

Comment: what's your real question? just directly use them in a using statement, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#logging-scopes).

Comment: Hi @IvanYang, I would like to see it in https://portal.azure.com, may you advise? thanks.

Comment: just check these scopes in azure portal? and what's your project, a web project?

Comment: Hi @IvanYang, may you guide me the steps to find beginScope "Testing Scope1" from Logs of Azure Functions/ Application Insights?

Comment: the scope value like "Testing Scope1" will be a custom property of the messages inside log.BeginScope(). eg. in the code `using(log.BeginScope("testing scope1")){log.LogError("this is an error");}`, then in azure portal -> your application insights, you should find the message "this is an error" in the `traces` table -> then in the `customDimensions` column, you can see the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code like below:

```
        using (_logger.BeginScope("Testing Scope1"))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("this is an info from index page 111111");
        }
```

Then, after the code is executed, nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> Logs -> in the `traces` table, write the following query(also note that select a proper "time range"):

```
traces
| where customDimensions.Scope contains "Testing Scope1"
| project message, customDimensions
```

The screenshot is as below:

[image]

By the way, it may take a few minutes for the logs being generated. And please also set the proper log level in your application(like [set the proper log level in your azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#log-levels-and-categories)).

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Yang! But when I used `traces
| where isnotnull(customDimensions.Scope)`, there is no result returned. My code is `log.BeginScope("Testing Scope1");` then `log.LogInformation("Test Info");`. Is it due to I did not use `using` so there is no result from searching result?

Comment: @DaiKeung, yes, please add `using`, then write the codes inside the `using` block like I did in the answer.